# jquery combining 2 scripts

Tags: jquery, hover, mousemove

Newbie to jquery here...

I have 2 jquery scripts that attach to 1 div.

1- scrolls inside the div (overflow) based on mousemove

```
    $("#navwrapper").mousemove(function(e){}
```

2- slides the whole thing in or out based on hover.

```
 $(function() { $('#navwrapper').hover( function () {}
```

I don't understand the different invocation methods either if someone would care to describe that to me as well....

Independently, (one or the other js commented out) they both work.  Together, it's whatever one comes first in the code that wins.

Is there a way to combine these two functionalities or calls?  I've read about bind but am not sure that's what i need to do here.

both are within a single $(document).ready(function() { } along with a bunch of other code  (that was removed to test).

Both of these are parts from stuff i found around the net, that i've hacked a bit to work for what i want.  I appreciate any help.

Thanks

fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/briansol/Y6hcs/

it doesn't perform perfectly in the fiddle due to the positioning elements it appears (ie, negative margins within the frames is off) so you might want to pull it out on to a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily chain these items together like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#navwrapper').hover( function () {
        // do something on hover
    }, function () {
        // do something on loss of hover
    }).mousemove(function (e) {
        // do something else
    });
});
```

Order in which the handlers are triggered depends on the actual order in which the events occur.

Comment: I'm having problems with this throwing expected ) and } errors. I think it's due to hover taking on the dual state of over/out.

Do you see what I did wrong here?

Comment: Oh yes, hover does require two functions as parameters. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. This works now, as far as clearing up the errors. But I'm back to square one in terms of fucntionality... I don't get the fly out on mouseover.  But the mouse scroll does work.

Comment: Interesting. it seems to conflict since they are both tyring to animate the same div. I commented out one of the regions to scroll (stop) and that area allows the fly out to happen.

So, how do i combine

$(this).stop().animate({ scrollTop: h }, speed*2);
with 
$('#navwrapper').stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-2px'},300);

when one is on hover and one is on mouse move.

Comment: Ok, looks like i'm heade in the right direction now--  I need to use the animate queue it looks like to go out with the menu, then up and down once its out.   I should be able to get it from here.  Thanks for the guidance, Mike.